# How do I include a separate custom cover page onto my LaTeX document?

Tags: pdf, covers

I've created a nice looking cover page in LaTeX as a pdf on its own. How do I add this onto an already existing LaTeX document instead of the default title page?

Comment: If you have the code of your cover you can use it on your main file. Or you simply join your two pdf files using some soft. On Linux, pdftk, for example.

Comment: In Mac OS, Preview has this functionality.

Answer (score 15):

You can wrap the code of your title page between `\begin{titlepage}` and `\end{titlepage}` right after your `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 9):

There is a special package to include pdfs as pages in your document. It is called "pdfpages". Read more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex

It may be a bit more tricky if you want the page to be numbered, and the numbering is not part of the original pdf. Please answer if this is the case - then, we can make a solution that adds the title page as an overlay tikz picture to the first page.